# is it possible to checkout to different server through ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to checkout the `develop` branch to my testing environment which is on a different server like this:

`git --work-tree=ssh://user@env.example.com/path/to/folder checkout -f develop`

However, I get the following error when run the script:

`fatal: Could not switch to 'ssh://maximus@testenv.inreado.com/var/www': ??? ?????? ????? ??? ????????`

Is it possible to checkout through ssh? If so, what could be the problem? It works fine if I checkout to local directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to only pull the remote branch?

`git pull ssh://user@env.example.com/path/to/folder develop`

ie.

`git pull remoteserver branchname`

Comment: no, there is no git repository setup on env.example.com

Comment: so a `git init` in the remote folder should be enough

Comment: yeah, I know :). I just want to export files from git repo.